# Can someone explain how the math in this solution works for me?

Tags: arithmetic

$$(1 \times 10^5) + (2 \times 2 \times 10^5) + (3 \times 5 \times 10^5) + (3 \times 2 \times 10^5) = 2.6 \times 10^6$$

I'd like to be able to do math like that without putting everything into a ti95 and working with a big number, but I can't figure out this method at all.

Thank you.

Comment: Let $x=10^5$, substitute it into your formula and try what you know on that, then substitute it back.

Comment: What you currently have written is false

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. I'll fix it.

Comment: Still looks incorrect.

Comment: https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/consider-two-different-implementations-of-the-same-instruction-set-architecture-the-instructions-can/
Here is the source.

Comment: Regardless of what the equation should be, to solve easily, treat $10^5$ as a variable. E.g. $(3×10^5) + (5×10^5) = 8×10^5$. Also recall that, if you had $20×10^5$ you could rewrite as $2×10×10^5 = 2×10^6$

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. I know how to solve it using that method now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$(1 \times 10^5) + (2 \times 2 \times 10^5) + (3 \times 5 \times 10^5) + (3\times 2 \times 10^5)$$
$$=(1+2\times2+3\times5+3\times2)\times10^5=(1+4+15+6)\times10^5$$
$$=26\times 10^{5}=2.6\times10^6.$$

Answer (score 0):

First factor out $10^5$:

$$ (1 \times 10^5) + (2\times2\times 10^5) + (3\times 5\times 10^5)+(3\times 2\times 10^5) = (1 + 2\times 2 + 3\times 5 + 3\times 2) \times 10^5$$

Then simplify coefficient of $10^5$:

$$(1 + 2\times 2 + 3\times 5 + 3\times 2) \times 10^5 = (1+4+15+6)\times 10^5 = 26\times 10^5 $$

Then simply note that $26 = 2.6\times 10$ and:

$$26\times 10^5 = 2.6\times 10\times 10^5 = 2.6\times 10^{5+1} = 2.6\times 10^6 $$